# How to setup php for multithreading on redhat 6.5

Tags: php, multithreading, installation

I've coded in C++ and Java with multi-threading.  I'd like to with PHP CLI, but haven't found a cut-and-dried method for setting the server up to allow multi-threading.  I'd like to be able to use worker threads if possible, but need to set our server up.  It is Redhat 6.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to recompile PHP with PECL pthreads. That said, why do you want multithreaded support? PHP is not designed with threading in-mind. You can already perform background operations via processes (which could be re-entrant back into the PHP script, if necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Prerequisites

To use `pthreads`, PHP must be built with thread safety enabled.

Note that, PHP **does** have a threading model, it **is** built with threaded architectures in mind.

However, it is not usually the default build mode for PHP, package maintainers tend to cater to the masses and the masses don't care about thread safety.

## Configuration

If you have PHP installed currently and are using it with an apache prefork mpm or some other non-thread-safe setup, then leave that installation intact. The best thing to do is build an isolated installation of PHP for use at the console.

The following example session illustrates how you might isolate an installation in /opt

```
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src
cd php-src
git checkout PHP-5.6
./buildconf
./configure --prefix=/opt --with-config-file-path=/opt --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/etc.d --enable-maintainer-zts
make
sudo make install
```

## Installing pthreads

With a thread safe build of PHP, installing pthreads is easy. The following example session illustrates how to install the latest pthreads sources

```
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads
cd pthreads
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Running the test suite distributed with pthreads is a good way to ensure everything is okay:

```
make test
```

To load pthreads all the time:

```
echo extension=pthreads.so > /opt/etc.d/pthreads.ini
```

Comment: So this will only affect the CLI and not Apache?  Also, would there be a benefit in making Apache/PHP multithreaded also?

Comment: It would build a new cli with threading support ... Threads at the frontend of an application rarely makes sense; if you instruct a program to create 8 threads upon receiving a request from a client and 100 clients show up at once, you are asking your hardware to execute 800 concurrent threads: I can't imagine what a CPU would have to look like to make that a good idea ;)

Comment: I see your point with Apache.  My current project runs nightly and populates multiple oracle tables from an external source.  I download data and load the tables.  It is limited to less than 10 threads and runs once a day.